# Jenkins with Docker - change URL

Tags: docker, jenkins, configuration

I'm currently trying to setup a jenkins environment with Docker, this is the documentation: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#on-macos-and-linux

The problem is: I can access the jenkins trough all my server like: test.com:8080 test2.com:8080 etc...
I want this, only accessible from test.com:8080

Does anyone have a solution ?

Best regards

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? You're saying that you can access your jenkins server at test.com:8080 but you actually want it to be accessed at test.com:8080? It seems like everything is working fine.

Comment: Hello, I want it ONLY acessible on test.com:8080, not test2.com:8080 :) (each test & test2 redirect to the same IP)

Comment: What OS? What webserver are you using? Is this cloud or bare-metal? If cloud, what provider? Do you have access to the DNS settings? I can't help if you don't provide any information. Pls edit your question to contain this information, also any configuration, be it apache or nginx or whatever, is helpful if we are looking into issues regarding IP resolution in DNS.